# How to add new list item with "Publishing Image" field in the list through list.asmx web service

Tags: publishing

I have a list called "post" which has the "publishing image" type column  has one of the column on the list.

Issue is need to add new item to list through [List.asmx] web service, need to know how to create soap message for updating the list with "publishing image"

Any ideas? please answer, thanks

Comment: "Publishing image" is the column type in list. it's nothing but the manually created site column of type "Image with formatting and constraints for publishing "

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what you are trying to do, but as Neelam shows, SPServices can help you. http://SPServices.codeplex.com

Comment: Hi Marc,  I am trying to add new list item using list.asmx web service in JQuery code, Issue is list has column of type "Publishing Image" which is added from existing site column of type [Image with formatting and constraints for publising]. This "Publishing Image" is a content type, i am not aware of how to send soap message for content type column. Please share your ideas. Thanks

Comment: I've never tried to created Publishing Pages with the Web Services; I avoid them in most cases I favor of list-based content.

Answer (score -1):

```
   var title="#ctl00_m_g_a681e990_6a42_4591_bfa2_70a90f97cd5b_ff1_new_ctl00_ctl00_TextField";
   var number="#ctl00_m_g_a681e990_6a42_4591_bfa2_70a90f97cd5b_ff2_new";
   var Name="#ctl00_m_g_a681e990_6a42_4591_bfa2_70a90f97cd5b_ff3_new";

      $().SPServices({//default
            operation: "UpdateListItems",//default
            async: false,//default
            listName: "Sample",//change
            updates:"<Batch OnError='Continue'>" +//default
            "<Method  ID='1' Cmd='New'>" +//default
                "<Field Name='Title'>" + $(title).val() + "</Field>" +    //change   
                "<Field Name='Number'>" +$(number).val()+ "</Field>"+
                "<Field Name='Name'>"+$(Name).val()+"</Field>"+
                "<Field Name='ID'></Field>" +//default
            "</Method>" +//default
        "</Batch>",//default
            completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
               // alert($(title).val());alert($(number).val());
           var title="";
     $("#ctl00_m_g_a681e990_6a42_4591_bfa2_70a90f97cd5b_ff1_new_ctl00_ctl00_TextField").val(title)
             //  $(ctl00_m_g_4e090343_dad2_40bc_937d_6716d78e4905_ff1_new_ctl00_ctl00_TextField).val()="";
           var number="";
           $("#ctl00_m_g_a681e990_6a42_4591_bfa2_70a90f97cd5b_ff2_new").val(number);                   
          var Name="";
      $("#ctl00_m_g_a681e990_6a42_4591_bfa2_70a90f97cd5b_ff3_new").val(Name);
                alert("Add new success.");                   
          }
        });
```

Comment: What were you trying to do here?